# Get total for User Timings in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, user-engagement, event-tracking

For an app in development, we need to track how much time our users (as a whole) spend watching content related to a specific entity.

We're trying to do that with User Timings with category "Entity Name", variable "Entity ID" (for instance category "Band", ID "The Rolling Stones").

This makes it very easy to get the *average* user timing (time spent) watching content per entity, but we also need to have a total computed. There seems to be no option to get this calculated, which seems weird since it's just the average multiplied by the number of samples collected.

Is there a way to get a "total" column in the User Timings report? 
Are we using the right tool for the job, or should we use something else?

Answer (score 2):

Make custom Reports with recently released Google Docs Add-On for Google Analytics more [here](http://googledrive.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/add-ons.html).
No need to learn Apps Scripts.

If you need more robust solution to integrate with your app use Google Reporting API [devguide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide)

Answer (score 0):

Why not multiply the average by the number of times it occurred?

Granted GA samples data but this is a simple mathematical operation that could be handled programmatically in a spreadsheet...not to mention manually in 10 seconds.

Comment: Manually is not an option (think thousands of different entities).
How can I get User Timing reports fed into a spreadsheet live?
This is not something we need to do once in a while, we need to access this at any time and have up-to-date data available. That's the deal with analytics.

Comment: I've found something related to spreadsheets but it involves Google Apps Scripts and, TBH, having to learn the Analytics API and go over that much work just to get two columns multiplied is too damn frustrating.

Comment: I can relate, sometimes I'm just too overwhelmed to learn something new right then. If the content loads from your server a server-side solution should suffice (look into what your hosting provides). Also, try browsing the Google Analytics App Gallery and the Google Docs (template) Gallery, maybe someone has built something that does this already.